# Show received image from Zoho

Tags: php, image, postman, zoho

I am using the Zoho Rest API to establish a connection between Zoho CRM and my client's WordPress website. With a request, I am trying to retrieve an image from Zoho (https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v6/get-files.html). This works fine, but I'm not entirely sure about the nature of what I receive:

[image]

I reached out to Zoho support for clarification, but they couldn't precisely identify the content received. They mentioned that they only perform requests with Postman, and the image is displayed correctly there. Indeed, when I use the same request with Postman, I can see the image instead of a string:

[image]

Does anyone happen to know what exactly I receive and how I can convert it into an image?

Comment: _"but I'm not entirely sure about the nature of what I receive"_ - that is clearly the binary content of a PNG image. You don't need to "convert" anything - you can write this to a file, then you'd have a valid image flie; or you can output it directly to the browser - after you sent an appropriate `Content-Type` header (and of course no other data in the same response.)

Answer (score 0):

CBroe is right.

Writing the content to a file, created the image I need:

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.png", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $content);
fclose($myfile);
```